# Merge transposed matrix back to image using opencv python

Tags: python, python-2.7, numpy, opencv, transpose

After loading an image using `cv2.imread(exmaple)` I can see the photo and use it. I want to split the image to b,g,r use B matrix, transpose it, and merge it again when all other channels are zeros. I'm getting this error:

> ```
> bluet = cv2.merge((mtrxz,mtrxz,bt))
> ```
>
> cv2.error: ......\modules\core\src\convert.cpp:296: error: (-215) mv[i].size == mv[0].size && mv[i].depth() == depth in function cv::merge

And here is my code:

```
def colors():
    img = cv2.imread('img.jpg')
    b,g,r = cv2.split(img)
    mtrxz = np.zeros(b.shape,np.uint8)

    bt = np.transpose(b)
    bluet = cv2.merge((mtrxz,mtrxz,bt))
```

Already try to:
1.Show it with `bluet = cv2.merge((mtrxz,mtrxz,bt))` And it's worked
2.Print **bt**, and see the matrix

Comment: Could you include the shape of your original image?  `img.shape`

Comment: print img.shape  -->> (2802L, 3558L, 3L)

Comment: That's the answer to your problem.  You can't merge with your original channels after transposing one of the channels because your image isn't square.  What you are doing will only work for a square image (N x N x 3).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see from your code you're not checking the matrices dimensions, thus transposing one channel (b) you have a mismatch with the other ones.
To be more clear here is an example:

t0.
 img.shape = (256x100) x 3
t1.
    transpose(b) => bt.shape = 100x256
t2.
    merge (256x100)x2 && (100x256) => Error!

I tried to transpose the zero matrices too and it worked for me. Here an example:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

img = cv2.imread('img.jpg')
b,g,r = cv2.split(img)
mtrxz = np.zeros(b.shape,np.uint8)

bt = np.transpose(b)
#bluet = cv2.merge((mtrxz,mtrxz,bt))
bluet = cv2.merge((np.transpose(mtrxz),np.transpose(mtrxz),bt))
```

Hope it will be helpful